# unexpected token "(" in c script

Tags: c, unix, process, fork

I am trying to write a c script that creates a child process and depending on the return it will print a message. I wrote this code so far:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main ()
{
 pid_t child_pid;
 printf ("the main program process ID is %d\n", (int) getpid()); 
 child_pid = fork() ; 
 if (child_pid==0){
    printf("this is the child process,with the id %d\n",(int) child_pid );
}
 else
    printf("this is the parent process with id %d\n",(int) getpid ());

 return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it it seems to be OK. But when I run it in terminal I get the following error:

```
./lab7.c: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./lab7.c: line 6: `int main ()'"
```

Can someone help me by telling me what I do wrong?

Comment: Next question: why does "the main program ..." string get printed twice?

Comment: how are you trying compilation? at my linux-box this code compiles successfully

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should check your logic a little closer... You have an `if` check if `child_pid` equals zero, and if it is you print out the value of `child_pid`., which means the child will always print it has pid zero.

Comment: I know that it must print twice because after the fork there are 2 processes but it doesn't do that.  gcc -o lab7 lab7.c .@Joachim Pileborg - that's a good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're executing the source code as a script instead of an executable, and, not surprisingly, whatever shell you're in doesn't like it.

You need to compile the code first, then execute the result of the compilation. For example, here we compile to produce an executable named `lab7` in the first line, and execute it in the second:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra lab7.c -o lab7
./lab7
```

Comment: This seems to work.Anyway it prints something.Can you explain a bit what -Wall -Wextra and a.out means.Since now i compiled with gcc -o lab7 lab7.c -the way i learned at school

Comment: @DamianAlex By default `gcc` will compile code with all kinds of problems. `Wall` means something like "all warnings". But that isn't enough. `Wextra` means "all warnings, plus some more". Even that isn't enough, but it is a good starting point. It will save you a lot of grief in the long run. If you're on a *nix platform, try `man gcc` or `gcc --help`.

Comment: after compilating if i run it : ./lab7.c it would give me the error mentioned above if i don't put .c it works

Comment: @DamianAlex Right, lab7.c is the source file, and doesn't mean anything to the shell you're running in.

Comment: You can't execute a C source file. You have to compile it and then execute the resulting executable file (which contains machine code, not C source code). That's why C programs are not generally referred to as "scripts"; that word is used for programs written in interpreted, not compiled, languages, like Perl, Python, or bash.